# I have problems with subfolder using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use mod_rewrite in a subfolder, but what ever I try I get 404 not found

www.mydomain.com/**gast**

I now have my .htaccess in the folder **gast**. What have I done wrong? If I use the same code (without **gast** in last line) in root it works for root

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^gast/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) /index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have .htaccess inside a subfolder then you don't start matching with subfolder but use subfolder in `RewriteBase`.

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gast/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus current directory starting from `DocumentRoot`) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: Thank you .. It works!
I tryed this before but I think I missed the secont backslash on line 2
:)